# Equivalence of representations

Tags: representation-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

Let $\pi$ be a finite dimensional unitary representation on a hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Then why is the left regular representation $L$ on $L^2(G,\mathcal{H})$ equivalent to $dim(\mathcal{H})L$?

Comment: What is $\dim\mathcal H$?

Comment: The vector space dimension of $\mathcal{H}$. $\pi$ is a finite dimensional representation. I will add this.

Comment: What exactly is the regular representation oon $L^2(G,H)$?

Comment: For $f\in L^2(G,\mathcal{H})$: $L(g)(f)(x):=f(g^{-1}x)$.

Comment: If the action of $G$ on $H$ is not used in that representation, then this is more or less obvious, no? Pick a basis of $H$ and consider the map from $L^2(G,H)$ to $L^2(G)^{\dim H}$ which maps a function to its "coordinates".

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the space correctly. Why is $L$ acting on each one-dimensional space separatly?

Comment: Because the formula for the action that you wrote in your comment above does not use anywhere the action of $G$ on $H$. (That's why I asked what the action was. One can put another action of $G$ on $L^2(G,H)$, setting $L(g)(f)(x)=g f(g^{-1}x)$, which *does* use the action of $G$ on $H$; then things are different.

Comment: So if $\{e_1,\ldots, e_n\}$ is a basis of $\mathcal{H}$ and $f\in L^2(G,\mathcal{H})$ one has $f(g)=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(g)e_i$ for some "coordinates" $f_i$. You mean this?

Comment: Yes. In general, for every finite dimensional vector space $V$ the regular representation of $G$ on $L^2(G,V)$ is isomorphic to $V\otimes L^2(G,\mathbb C)$, by the same argument. Alternatively, for every pair of vector spaces $V$ and $W$ you have that $L^2(G,V\oplus W)$ is isomorphic to $L^2(G,V)\oplus L^2(G,W)$; using this, induction, and a decomposition of $H$ as a direct sum on $1$-dimensional vector spaces gives you the result.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please write a complete answer, so that the question does not remain unanswered.